# 2-forms represented by a first Chern class?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, characteristic-classes

Let $M$ be a complex manifold and $\omega$ be a 2-form on $M$. Is there a good way to see whether $\omega$ is represented by the first Chern class of a line bundle on $M$? In other words, when is it of the form $\omega=2\pi i c_1(L)$ for a line bundle $L$ on $M$?

Comment: If $M$ is Kaehler, the answer is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_theorem_on_(1,1)-classes

Comment: $\omega$ needs to be a $(1,1)$-form and an integral class (that is, in the image of $H^2(M,\mathbb Z) \to H^2(M,\mathbb R)$), then a lemma of André Weil (that you can prove; think Cech cohomology) gives a line bundle $L$ such that $\omega \in (i/2\pi) c_1(L)$.

Comment: For additional credit, find necessary and sufficient conditions for a collection of $2k$-forms $c_1, \ldots, c_r$ to be the Chern forms of a rank $r$ vector bundle $E \to M$. Then publish in a swanky journal.